# How can I refactor this setState by looping through the object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I feel like this should be much easier than I'm finding it...

Right now, I have this code, and it works:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API_URL + `/interviews/general/${this.props.employeeId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          organization: result[0].organization,
          address: result[0].address,
          website: result[0].website,
          industry: result[0].industry,
          co_status: result[0].co_status,
          mission: result[0].mission,
          
        });
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

The issue is that this is actually data that I'm retrieving and then displaying the results in a form.  BUt this is just part of it.  There are actually closer to 50 key value pairs in this object.  There has to be a way from me to loop through that setState, right?

This is what "result" looks like, which is what my fetch returns:

```
[{…}]
0:
COBRA_admin: ""
address: "1914 Skillman St, Suite 110153, Dallas, TX 75206"
benefits_broker: ""
co_status: "Private"
created_at: "2020-09-29T01:54:48.000Z"
employee_id: 104
general_id: 24
headcount_consultants: 0
headcount_fulltime: 0
headcount_nonexempt: 0
headcount_parttime: 0
headcount_temp: 0
hrlead_email: ""
hrlead_name: ""
hrlead_phone: ""
hrlead_title: ""
industry: "HR Consulting"
locations: ""
locations_headcount: ""
mission: "TO go and do great things. "
organization: "People Performance Resources LLC"
pointofcontact_email: ""
pointofcontact_name: ""
pointofcontact_phone: ""
pointofcontact_title: ""
retirement_admin: ""
seniorlead_email: ""
seniorlead_name: ""
seniorlead_phone: ""
seniorlead_title: ""
updated_at: "2020-09-30T20:47:39.000Z"
website: "www.pprhr.com"
```

Comment: Are there any keys in `result[0]` that you do **not** want to put on the state?

Comment: What's `result`?

Comment: What does the `result` object look like and what is your expected state object shape to be?

Comment: Sorry I should have been specific with that initially.  I have included what "resutl" looks like in my post now.

Comment: And yes, I want all of them.  Nothing excluded.

Comment: `I want all of them. Nothing excluded.` then do `this.setState(results[0])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want all the keys, just do:

```js
this.setState({...result[0]});
```

Comment: Wow.... I knew there had to be an easier way... but had no idea it was that easy!  lol  This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a map function to loop the data and return the values in a state variable that will maintain the values for the entire results array for a specific key.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(API_URL + `/interviews/general/${this.props.employeeId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw new Error();
        }
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          organizations: result.map(item => item.organization),
          addresses: result.map(item => item.address),
          websites: result.map(item => item.website),
          industries: result.map(item => item.industry),
          co_status: result.map(item => item.co_status),
          missions: result.map(item => item.mission),   
        });
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

To display the data

```
// pass missions as a prop
const App = ({ missions }) => { 
 return (
    <ul> {missions.map(mission => <li> {mission} </li>)} </ul>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind considering [deconstruction statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), beside with [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), please look into pseudocode:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch( <url> );
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const {
      organization, address, website, industry, co_status, mission
    } = response.json(); // deconstruction

    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      organization,
      address,
      website,
      industry,
      co_status,
      mission
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error(error.message);
  }
}
```

However those functionalities covers same functionality, please be aware that those statements are not equal. Please take a look to get know what is a difference [async/await vs Promisses](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-stack-traces), keyword is stack trace.

If you are looking for some good must know fundamentals, please visit:
[JavaScript to Know for React](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/javascript-to-know-for-react) by Kent C. Dodds